# Why Jmeter RTE protocol is not supporting back office screens?

Tags: jmeter

While recording Back Office screens using Jmeter RTE plugin (v2.3) , getting the below error after entering login creds.

Jmeter version - 5.2.1 , RTE plugin version - 2.3

Any help on this please ?

```
2020-04-07 16:17:32,033 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.orders.StartFieldExtendedOrder.<init>(StartFieldExtendedOrder.java:45) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.orders.Order.getOrder(Order.java:47) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.commands.WriteCommand.<init>(WriteCommand.java:38) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.commands.Command.getCommand(Command.java:108) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.streams.TelnetListener.processRecord(TelnetListener.java:98) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.telnet.TelnetProcessor.listen(TelnetProcessor.java:62) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.streams.TelnetListener.listen(TelnetListener.java:58) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.streams.TerminalServer.run(TerminalServer.java:74) ~[dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your RTE plugin installation got broken somewhere somehow, [RTE Plugin 2.3](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin/releases/tag/v2.3) should come with [`dm3270-lib-0.12.1.jar`](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin/releases/download/v2.3/dm3270-lib-0.12.1.jar)

[image]

And looking into your stacktrace I can see `dm3270-lib-0.11.1.jar` is being used so it might be the case you have an older version of the library in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

So first of all I would recommend clean installation of the [latest stable JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) followed by the latest JMeter Plugins Manager and the latest RTE Plugin

You might also be interested in [Using JMeter's RTE plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-rte-plugin/) which provides instructions on manually building the RTE test plan